# Coldfusion 2016 and IIS Tomcat ISAPI Filter

Tags: tomcat, iis, coldfusion

I've set up a new ColdFusion 2016 server with IIS 7. Set up the first site with no issues. Now I want to set up a second site - have created it and no IIS errors. BUT, in IIS > Features View > ISAPI Filters, both sites are using the same Tomcat executable path:

C:\ColdFusion2016\config\wsconfig\2\isapi_redirect.dll

I want a different executable path for Tomcat for each site depending on their folder in wsconfig, so site 1 points to: 
C:\ColdFusion2016\config\wsconfig\**2**\isapi_redirect.dll

And site 2 points to:
C:\ColdFusion2016\config\wsconfig\**1**\isapi_redirect.dll.

But I can't get this to happen - changing the tomcat executable path for one website in IIS also changes the other. Any ideas?

Comment: Run the Web Server Connection Tool and add each site individually rather then selecting all. This should create a different numbered folder in wsconfig

Comment: @haxtbh - you should post that as the answer.

Comment: I've done this - each site has a different numbered folder from the connection tool. The problem lies with IIS and it only allowing one Tomcat entry in the ISAPI filters section. If I update the tomcat executable path for one site (to point to the correct wsconfig folder), it changes it for all sites.

Comment: Try giving the ISAPI filters in IIS different names. Like `Tomcat1` under web site 1 and `Tomcat2` under web site 2. Also, you may not get this working if the ISAPI filter is defined globally. I think you will need to define each one under it's appropriate web site in IIS.